# play! 1.2.4 Module not found: /Users/mxia/exec/play-1.2.4/modules/runclass

Tags: playframework

I'm trying to get a project that uses play! 1.2.4 working.

We are using maven and I ran the following command after unzipping play from http://downloads.typesafe.com/releases/play-1.2.4.zip

`play install maven`

```
~ Will install maven-head
~ This module is compatible with: 1.1
~ Do you want to install this version (y/n)? y
~ Installing module maven-head...
~
~ Fetching http://www.playframework.org/modules/maven-head.zip
~ [--------------------------100%-------------------------] 34760.7 KiB/s   
~ Unzipping...
~
~ Module maven-head is installed!
~ You can now use it by adding it to the dependencies.yml file:
~
~ require:
~     play -> maven head`
```

Then I did `play mvn:refresh`

but it complains

```
~ Oops,
~ Module not found: /myPath/play-1.2.4/modules/runclass
```

Anyone know where I can get this runclass module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have install the maven module to your local play repository.
But this module is not enable for your project.

You have to add this line into your dependencies.yml :
require:
  play -> maven head`

Then run the command "play dependencies" on your project, and everything should be good.